# request data from front end (d3.json) from python flask backend

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, flask

Python user, learning some basic javascript:

I have created a simple flask app for demonstration. (For a quick test, I've put this example on Github: https://github.com/robertdavidwest/flask_d3_example)

```
dependencies:
- python=3.7.1
- flask=1.0.2
- flask-cors=3.0.7
```

and https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js

APP:

```
.
├── run.py
├── static
│   └── js
│       └── data.js
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

I'm serving data from a flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route("/get-data")
def get_data():
    return jsonify({"a": 1, "b": 2})
```

With the server running, if I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-data then I see the data.

But when I try to use `d3.json` to request the data from the front end, nothing seems to happen (I've tried logging the data and writing to a div):

```
d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-data",
  function(d){
     console.log(d);
     document.getElementById("d3-write-here").innerHTML = d;
 })
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Details of all code in simple app:

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang='en'>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Simple Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Nothing much here</h2>
  <div id="d3-write-here"></div>

 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/data.js') }}">
 </script>
```

run.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/get-data")
def get_data():
    return jsonify({"a": 1, "b": 2})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

static/js/data.js:

```
d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-data",
  function(d){
    console.log(d);
    document.getElementById("d3-write-here").innerHTML = d;
  })
```

Comment: d3v5 use fetch (Promises), doc d3-fetch, be aware of CORS

Answer (score 0):

In d3 v5, you need to use a different syntax for the json call.

Try:

```
d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-data").then(
  function(d){
    console.log(d);
    document.getElementById("d3-write-here").innerHTML = d;
  })
```